Can't Read Regex From YAML File
I created a yaml file for my project's configuration file and I get this error when trying to pull the regex from this yaml file.
Error:
exception in thread "main" while scanning a double-quoted scalar
config.yml
regex: "\\((.*?)\\)"

I edited my configuration file as follows and the error is resolved
config.yml
regex: "\((.*?)\)"

But this time I break the regex and my filtering is not successful
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(config.getRegex()).matcher(message);


This article suggests using a single quote instead of double https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/1422

Should not it be just regex: \((.*?)\)? Also, single quotes are fine, too.
